# how to do custom filter in angular JS and what should be the return type

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, mean-stack

I am using MEAN stack and trying to filter the data from the ng-repeat.
Here goes my HTML code

```
<section data-ng-controller="BookingsController" data-ng-init="find()">
<div data-ng-repeat="x in bookings|filter:select_booking" data-ng-href="#!/bookings/{{booking._id}}" class="list-group-item">
            <label>Booking ID :</label>{{x.booking_id}}
            <label>Membership ID :</label>{{x.membership_id}}
            <label>Check Out Date :</label>{{ x.checkout_time | date : "longDate" }}
            <label>Rooms :</label><span ng-repeat="room in booking.room_id">{{room}}&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <button class="pull-right" value="Block" ng-click="checkout(x)">Check Out</button>
            <button class="pull-right" style="margin-right:10px" value="Block" ng-click="services(x)">Add Services</button>
            <br>
        </div>
</section>
```

My filter name in the above code is **select_booking**. 
The code for ng-controller goes here

```
$scope.checkindetails = CheckinDetails.query();/*accessing the mongo db values*/
$scope.select_booking = function (a) {
            var f = 0;
            jQuery.each($scope.checkindetails, function (key, val) {
                if (val.booking_id == a.booking_id) {
                    console.log("in if");
                    console.log(a.booking_id);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        };
```

My Console.log result:

```
bookings.client.controller.js:300in if
bookings.client.controller.js:301 ASHISH_BOOK_002
bookings.client.controller.js:300 in if
bookings.client.controller.js:301 ASHISH_BOOK_000
```

**bookings db:here referred as a**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54f02f7ba3c39d8c106bd3f7"),
        "user" : ObjectId("54eede3363b3e60c2133fe06"),
        "created" : ISODate("2015-02-27T08:48:59.890Z"),
        "date_of_cancellation" : "",
        "cancelled" : "No",
        "points" : 0,
        "booking_id" : "ASHISH_BOOK_000",
        "checked_out" : "Yes",
        "booking_date" : ISODate("2015-02-27T08:48:59.890Z"
        "adult_count" : 4,
        "room_id" : [
                "101",
                "102"
        ],
        "rooms_count" : 2,
        "resort_id" : "ASH_RESORT001",
        "checkout_time" : "2015-02-28T18:30:00.000Z",
        "checkin_time" : "2015-02-26T18:30:00.000Z",
        "guest" : "no",
        "membership_id" : "4",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54f560e2e0d3bed8069214f5"),
        "user" : ObjectId("54ec4eb13d50decc1f5307b4"),
        "created" : ISODate("2015-03-03T07:21:06.386Z"),
        "date_of_cancellation" : "",
        "cancelled" : "No",
        "points" : 0,
        "booking_id" : "ASHISH_BOOK_001",
        "checked_out" : "Yes",
        "booking_date" : ISODate("2015-03-03T07:21:06.386Z"
        "adult_count" : 4,
        "room_id" : [
                "100",
                "101"
        ],
        "rooms_count" : 2,
        "resort_id" : "ASH_RESORT002",
        "checkout_time" : "2015-03-03T18:30:00.000Z",
        "checkin_time" : "2015-03-02T18:30:00.000Z",
        "guest" : "no",
        "membership_id" : "1",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54f6942195002c140700dac0"),
        "user" : ObjectId("54ec4eb13d50decc1f5307b4"),
        "created" : ISODate("2015-03-04T05:12:01.211Z"),
        "date_of_cancellation" : "",
        "cancelled" : "No",
        "points" : 0,
        "booking_id" : "ASHISH_BOOK_002",
        "checked_out" : "Yes",
        "booking_date" : ISODate("2015-03-04T05:12:01.211Z"
        "adult_count" : 2,
        "room_id" : [
                "103"
        ],
        "rooms_count" : 1,
        "resort_id" : "ASH_RESORT001",
        "checkout_time" : "2015-03-04T18:30:00.000Z",
        "checkin_time" : "2015-03-03T18:30:00.000Z",
        "guest" : "no",
        "membership_id" : "1",
        "__v" : 0
}
```

checkindetails db:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54f06257d75533c01add0cf0"),
        "user" : ObjectId("54ec4eb13d50decc1f5307b4"),
        "created" : ISODate("2015-02-27T12:25:59.185Z"),
        "id_proof_type" : "abcd",
        "address" : "bangalore",
        "guest_name" : "Harshavardhan",
        "booking_id" : "ASHISH_BOOK_000",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54f696b095002c140700dac4"),
        "user" : ObjectId("54ec4eb13d50decc1f5307b4"),
        "created" : ISODate("2015-03-04T05:22:56.498Z"),
        "id_proof_type" : "okoko",
        "address" : "okoko",
        "guest_name" : "kok",
        "booking_id" : "ASHISH_BOOK_002",
        "__v" : 0
}
```

I am able to reach till console.log(a.booking_id);
Here I am comparing the booking_id of **a**(input parameter) with the booking_id of **checkindetails** and I want the result value of matching booking_id.
The console.log is providing me the correct answer but when I return that console.log value I am getting a blank answer.

Please Help me to find the correct One.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Angularjs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) a filter:

> Selects a subset of items from array and returns it as a new array.

Think of the filter as a subset of your original data, that subset is defined within the function that is called when you use that filter.

So in your example you would define your filter "select_booking" to return the filtered values.  They can be partial matches by default, or exact matches by adding.."...**:true**" to the end.

If you want to match the id, you should return the actual id, not "true".

```
return a.booking_id;
```

If your filter returns a single id, your ng-repeat will show all bookings with that id.  As a side note, if it is an "id" I would use the exact match like...

```
"book in bookings|filter:{id:select_booking}:true"
```

That would be how to set it up.  Your return type is what you are filtering.  If I'm filtering an array of numbers I return numbers.  If I'm filtering text, I return text ect.